# update linq to sql values with select new keyword

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

How to update linq to sql values with select new keyword with anonymous types because I am using `var` keyword with select new query I need in in this but it returns an error like this

> Compiler Error Message: CS0200: Property or indexer 'AnonymousType#1.Code' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only

This is my code:

```
var ProjectView12 = (from x in db.Projects
select new 
{
    add = db.Locations.Where(y = > y.ID == x.RegionID).FirstOrDefault().Name,
    Province = db.Locations.Where(y = > y.ID == x.ProvinceID).FirstOrDefault().Name,
    District = db.Locations.Where(y = > y.ID == x.DistrictID).FirstOrDefault().Name,
    Code = x.Code,
    Name = x.Name,
    ProjectIdentificationDate = db.Milestones.Where(y = > y.ProjectID == x.ID && y.StageID == 1 && y.ComponentID == 1 && y.ModuleID == 1).FirstOrDefault().Date.ToString(),
    ProjectLat = Convert.ToDecimal(x.Lat),
    ProjectLong = Convert.ToDecimal(x.Lon),
    Remarks = db.Milestones.Where(y = > y.ProjectID == x.ID && y.StageID == 1 && y.ComponentID == 1 && y.ModuleID == 1).FirstOrDefault().Remarks.ToString(),
}).ToList();

foreach(var item in ProjectView12) 
{
    item.Code = txtSubProjectCode.Text;
    item.Name = txtSubProjectName.Text;
    item.ProjectLat = Convert.ToDecimal(txtLatitude.Text);
    item.ProjectLong = Convert.ToDecimal(txtLongitude.Text);
    item.ProjectIdentificationDate = txtDate.Text;
    item.Remarks = txtRemarks.Text;
} //    txtLocation.Text = item.Region + ">" + item.Province + ">" + item.District;

try 
{
    db.SubmitChanges();
}
catch (Exception ex) 
{
    throw ex;
}
```

Comment: calling save changes on anonymous type does not make any sense. What if that anonymous type has property called Count and you just change it and call save.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, you're getting the compiler error because - as it says - the properties of anonymous types are read-only in C#.

More fundamentally, even if you *could* modify them, you'd have to expect LINQ to SQL to reverse whatever you put into your projection in order to update the original tables. That seems a fairly tall order to me - particularly for the `Remarks` property in this particular case.

Basically, in order to update the database, you need to make changes to the entities that are mapped from your tables. Make your query select the relevant entities, then you can project from those later on in client-side code, if necessary - so long as you've still got a reference to the entity to modify.